# NodeJs started, working but nothing is displayed

Tags: node.js, openshift

I am working on a NodeJs/Angular application that is based on the article example provided through the MEAN.js stack. I have been spending many hours developing things, and everything worked fine - until just now.

When I start my application using 'npm start' my app is found and everything seems to work as expected, but nothing is shown in my browser, even though it seems like all scripts can be found and the browser receives HTML.

When I inspect the source code in the browser window it shows a complete HTML file with all required CSS and JS files. The files can be found; clicking on a link shows the source.

I did an 'npm update' recently, and I suspect that the problems started there. Maybe there is an updated  external module that doesn't interact with some other module, but I have no idea how I can find out which one.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: i see in console JQuery is missing `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery1`

Comment: Open the browser's JavaScript console. There are quite a lot of errors there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing JQuery in `<script>`

Comment: Thanx a lot! I had a reference to jquery/dist/jquery.js, but after the update there was no dist directory. Updated the path, it's working again. Thanks again!

Comment: cool, could you pls also upvote it if it's helpful to you, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I can't - not enough reputation :-(